# XAML Style only applied after second instance when using MergedDictionaries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've observed that when defining a custom button style inside a `MergedDictionaries` tag, the style is only applied on the second (and all others) instance of the control.
It does not happen when I omit the `MergedDictionaries` and proceeding `ResourceDictionary` tag.

Oddly, the Visual Studio (2015) designer shows my expected appearance - it's only at runtime that the error occurs.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style x:Key="mybutton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Border  BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource mybutton}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Height="100" />
        <Button Height="50" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Note this is a completely blank template other than the XAML above:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the MergedDictionaries right, according to this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

"Dictionaries are merged by adding a ResourceDictionary to the generic collection referenced by MergedDictionaries. A merged ResourceDictionary does not have resource elements defined within it in markup. Instead, the merged dictionary is a ResourceDictionary with no markup child elements defined (or with no elements added through code), but with a URI specified for Source. "

You can easily write the styles like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="mybutton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border  BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource mybutton}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Height="100" />
        <Button Height="50" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```